# Reduce space In GridLayout

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, grid-layout

I have a component with 1 Grid Layout

`<GridLayout class="gridDate" columns="auto, auto" >`
And in this Grid I have 2 Items. For sure each item take full place of column but item is so big it is for that I reduce them like this `transform: scale(0.7);` for both. But my problem it is I have a space between them and I would like tou know how I can handle them (for example I would like to move item 2 on the left side of the second column.

Best regard and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

`columns="*,*"` would take the full width of the screen, which you can then adjust with css margin and padding styling.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this with `columns="*, *"`  and a margin 0 on red part (

````
background-color: red;
transform: scale(0.7);
margin-left: 0px;```
 but 0 changes 
[Image of Gridlayout with components][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2JHF.jpg
````

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? Also, with NativeScript, you don't need the "px" on the margin setting.